# Flutter: How can I increase radius of border in Circle Image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have class CircleImage, with this I try to control radius of circle image and CircleBorder, but i can't do it. I saw, that I have to use Circle avatar with Border. I try to solve this problem a whole day, please help me:)

> This my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircleImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageSource;
  final double size;

  CircleImage({@required this.imageSource, this.size}) : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: size ?? 55,
        height: size ?? 55,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            shape: CircleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: AssetImage(imageSource),
                alignment: Alignment.center)));
  }
}
```

> What that I have in this moment
>   [image: What that I have in this moment]

Comment: what do you mean by "increase the value of border"?

Comment: if you want a thicker border, change the width.

Comment: I mean increase the radius of border

Comment: width: size ?? 75,
height: size ?? 75,

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: changing the width and height of the container will make the circle larger, thus increasing the radius of the circle

Comment: when you call the class, are you adding an optional size variable? if so, change it there

Comment: Yeah, i know, but it won't increase border radius

Comment: what do you mean by border radius? are you talking about a rounded rectangle and not a circle?

Comment: Yeah you right, i mean about this

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a RoundedRectangleBorder, not a CircleBorder.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        side: BorderSide(
          width: 1,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
        ),
      ),
```

Then, you can change the border radius as you wish...

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), // CHANGE BORDER RADIUS HERE
        side: BorderSide(
          width: 1,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CircleAvatar inside a CircleAvatar, like this:

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 33.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        radius: 30.0,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/text-image.png'),
    ),
),
```

The difference in radius between the outer and inner CircleAvatar **radius** properties will be the border thickness.

In this case, it creates a blue border.